# Difference between Combobox properties SelText and Text?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I don't quite understand the differences between the combobox properties `SelText` and `Text`.

If I want to send the content of a combobox as a parameter to another procedure, should I send `.text` or `.selText`?

If I want to make enter text into a combobox using a macro, should I write the text in `.selText` or `.Text`?

Comment: Are you talking about the ActiveX control or the one in UserForm? My guess is ActiveX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is really given in the name (**Sel**Text vs. Text) where **Sel** stands for `Selected`.  One is used to return or modify the selected text (i.e. `SelText`) and the other is used to return or modify the entire text (i.e. `Text`).

If no text is selected in the ComboBox then they return and modify the same value.

I suspect you want to use `Text` unless you are specifically interested in the selected text.

This appears to be consistent for an ActiveX control on a `Worksheet` or for a control on a User Form.

Comment: Just to be clear, since the term "Selected" is used ambiguously with regard to CombBox controls: what Byron Wall is referring to for the SelText property is any user-selected *sub-string part* of the ComboBox control's displayed value, not necessarily the (entire) value of the Selected list-item itself, which is what the Text property returns.